# android sdk update

Tags: android, eclipse

I have just updated android-sdk but it started to give error for my sdk is version 18 which is below 20. But actually my android-sdk version is 20. I don't want to reinstall sdk. What should I do ?

Comment: I have added so many libraries on sdk so I don't want to reinstall it. But if there is no solution I have to reinstall :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your Eclipse Under Menu **Help**  **>**  **Check for Updates**  and update your ADT

Comment: I have reinstall the sdk and made an update on eclipse. And it worked ! Thanks